# Error in Vite Preview: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, svelte, vite

I'm facing this `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data` error when using `vite preview` after `vite build`.
[image: screenshot of error message]

My `vite.config.js`:

```js
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import { svelte } from "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte";

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    base: "/weatherdatacollector_baku/",
    plugins: [svelte()],
});
```

I'm not facing this issue when i use `yarn dev`.
How can i solve this issue

Comment: Find out which line of code throws the error then go from there

Comment: Had the same error and determined it was from having an 'undedined' value in local storage (set via svelte-local-storage-store module) so you might want to check that if you haven't already solved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try importing your JSON directly into you main.js file

```js
import json from "./example.json";
console.log(json)
```

You should still be able to use async by referring whatever name you use to import.